# Can't INSERT data into database using sqlite and pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qtsql

I am using Pycharm 2017.3. My python version is 3.4.
I am trying to insert data into table using sqlite4 and pyqt.
I have successfully created a table but could not insert even a single data.

Here is what I am importing

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
site_pack_path = "C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages"
QApplication.addLibraryPath('{0}\\PyQt4\\plugins'.format(site_pack_path))
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
```

Here is how I have created a table

```
query.exec_("CREATE TABLE dictin(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            "word varchar(100), searchShortDefn varchar(300),mnemonics varchar(500), "
            "defArr varchar(500), defDict varchar(500))")
```

Then there is a function whose purpose is to insert data into table which is not working.

```
def getWordsAndInsert(word, searchShortDefn, mnemonics, defArr, defDict):

    word=str(word)
    searchShortDefn=str(searchShortDefn)
    mnemonics=str(mnemonics)
    defArr=str(defArr)
    defDict=str(defDict)
    print(query.exec_("INSERT INTO dictin(word, searchShortDefn, mnemonics, defArr, defDict) "
                      "VALUES(word, searchShortDefn, mnemonics, defArr, defDict)"))
```

As you can see that I have converted everything to string as my contents are not string.
Type of the argument being passed to the getWordsAndInsert method is

```
 class 'str'
 class 'str' 
 class 'str' 
 class 'list'
 class 'list'
```

respectively.

Here is the example of the function getWordsAndInsert being called

```
getWordsAndInsert("abbreviate",
              "shorten",
              "abbreviate consists of brevity(means brief)",
              ['(verb) reduce in scope while retaining essential elements', '(verb) shorten'],
              [{'syn': ['renounce'], 'sent': ['The King abdicated when he married a divorcee']}])
```

Though I can insert when I replace variables with actual string but obviously it does not get the work done.

```
 print(query.exec_("INSERT INTO dictin(word, searchShortDefn, mnemonics, defArr, defDict) "
                  "VALUES('word', 'searchShortDefn', 'mnemonics', 'defArr', 'defDict')"))
```

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], currently your code is not.

Comment: I have added an example if any one want to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To establish the values in the query we can use [`prepare()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsqlquery.html#prepare), where we establish placeholders for the data, these placeholders we fill in through [`bindValue()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsqlquery.html#bindValue):

```
def getWordsAndInsert(word, searchShortDefn, mnemonics, defArr, defDict):
    word = str(word)
    searchShortDefn = str(searchShortDefn)
    mnemonics = str(mnemonics)
    defArr = str(defArr)
    defDict = str(defDict)

    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.prepare("""INSERT INTO dictin (word, searchShortDefn, mnemonics, defArr, defDict)
        VALUES (:word, :searchShortDefn, :mnemonics, :defArr, :defDict)""")

    query.bindValue(":word", word)
    query.bindValue(":searchShortDefn", searchShortDefn)
    query.bindValue(":mnemonics", mnemonics)
    query.bindValue(":defArr", defArr)
    query.bindValue(":defDict", defDict)

    if query.exec_():
        print("Successful")
    else:
        print("Error: ", query.lastError().text())
```